# Bump version without recompiling assembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

**Question**

Is it possible to modify the version data of an assembly without re-compiling it ?

**Context**

Our project is a C# / .Net-core project.

Say we build assemblies, and set their `File version` to `5.0.7-rc3`.

If these assemblies are validated, is there a way to "promote" them to `5.0.7` without recompiling them ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change compiled assembly version information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33664533/change-compiled-assembly-version-information)

Comment: Very misleading answers.  If you don't use the /win32res compile option then the compiler generates the unmanaged version resource automatically.  Which is the one that you look at when you look at the file properties with Explorer.  The native UpdateResource() function is not practical to alter that resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use [dnSpy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy) It's a debugger and .NET assembly editor.

You can `drag and drop` the `assembly.dll` in to dnSpy and and right click and select `Edit Module` and under `Version` you can modify it.

[image: Example Usage]

---

You can also use [rcedit](https://github.com/electron/rcedit). As lifted from the GitHub page:

Set file version:

```
$ rcedit "path-to-exe-or-dll" --set-file-version "10.7"
```

Set product version:

```
$ rcedit "path-to-exe-or-dll" --set-product-version "10.7"
```

Comment: He does not want to modify [AssemblyVersion].

Comment: The rcedit option would be the kind of tool to use. I'm not working on that project anymore, and I haven't tested it on that real project though.